# How to indent (add padding) to a dynamically-created column in a GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is created dynamically at run-time (the code is in the .cs class).

The columns are added to the GridView by iterating through this code for all columns:

```
BoundField field = new BoundField();
field.HeaderText = element.Heading;
field.DataField = element.FieldName;
Column is added to the GridView.
TableGridView.Columns.Add(field);
```

I would like to add a padding-left style attribute to the first column. How exactly am I to do this through the C# code? As far as I know, I cannot do this by writing ASP.NET code since the columns are generated at run-time in the C# class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CSS class with the padding-left specified, then:

```
field.ControlStyle.CssClass = "CssClassWithLeftPadding";
```

EDIT: Ok I added this to a code-behind:

```
     var field = new BoundField();
     field.ItemStyle.CssClass = "left_padding";
     field.HeaderText = "Item";
     field.DataField = "Item";
     grdSubject.Columns.Add(field);

     grdSubject.DataSource = (new[] {"This", "is", "padded"}).Select(x=>new {Item = x});
     grdSubject.DataBind();
```

..and this:

```
<style>
  .left_padding
  {
     padding-left:5px;
  }
```

Comment: Tried it, but it didnt work - nothing happened. I also tried 'ItemStyle' instead of ControlStyle, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can also work:

field.Attributes.Add("style","padding:5px;");

Comment: Doesn't work - 'Attributes' cannot be used with a BoundField.

Comment: How about field.Control.Attributes.Add(...);? does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the DataFormatString:

```
BoundField field = new BoundField();
field.DataFormatString = "{0,10}";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: Tried it, didnt work either. Thanks for the help, do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Doh.  Html will strip white space.  This is kind of klunky but you could try a format string like:  "&nbsp;&nbsp;{0}"  Or try setting HtmlEncode to false on the field.